# PouchDB+Couchbase+Sync Gateway Cookie authentication

Tags: angularjs, cookies, couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have following scenario:

PouchDB sends user login info into application server:

```
POST /api/login
{user:'test', password:'test'}
```

Application server authenticates into Sync Gateway:

```
POST /sync_gateway/_sessions/
```

Obtained Cookie is being returned to angular application:

```
"SyncGatewaySession=89498ca5a159ff086a3cb1da2370eb36249936x5"
```

Question is how to configure PouchDB to authenticate with that cookie.

Ive tried [setting cookie header](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pouchdb/2b5q8yGTi8o/lLy4N8bZ1swJ) but no luck.

Will appreciate any tips.

Comment: got any solution? i am facing same issue. appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication via direct usage of the REST API somehow does not work for subsequent requests (I faced the same problem).
Please make use of the pouchdb-authentication plugin. It works perfectly fine. Here's the link:
https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication

Comment: Thanks. But there is incompatibility with Sync Gateway i am talking about post to /_sessions whereas sync gateway expects /dbname/_sessions

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the "Authentication" header with encoded username and password combination instead of the cookie header. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use the admin REST API to create a sessoin, then pass the session in another header than `Cookie` and use nginx to pass the custom header as cookie to sync gateway, like this:

```
proxy_set_header Cookie "$cookie_SGSession";
```